# How exactly do 1950's rotary phones receive phone calls?

Tags: telephone, rotary

What happens start to finish. For example, how does the signal get from the central office to the phone and what mechanisms within the phone move to signal that a phone call is coming?

Comment: You could do worse starting at the Wikipedia page for POTS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes for being too broad. It's a general question, but it shouldn't take a book to answer.

Comment: @Adam Haun: If you think the answer below answers even 20% of the question precisely as asked, then you don't know much about POTS.

Comment: After a bit looking through GB, I can recommend you "Understanding Telephone Electronics" as further reading; Just look at their page[s] on ringing to see what you're missing :) https://books.google.com/books?id=ITe2DyrbtdsC&pg=PA66

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Fair enough.

Answer (score 6):

The way standard corded landline phones work hasn't changed much. That is why you can often still use old phones on a modern phone line.

When a phone line is idle there is about 50V DC between the two wires. When it rings the exchange superimposed a low frequency AC ringing voltage (about 100V iirc) on the DC. The ringer in the phone is connected to the line via a capacitor so it isn't affected by the constant DC but is caused to ring by the AC. In phones from the 50s the ringer is an electromechanical bell.

When someone picks up the phone the main phone components are connected to the phone line and presents a DC load (phones typically used carbon granule microphones which required DC power). The exchange detects this load (IIRC in the old days this was done by connecting relay coils in series with the supply to the phone line). If the phone was ringing the exchange exchange stops the ringing and connects the call. If the phone was not ringing the exchange presents a dialtone and waits for the user to dial. An analog circuit known as a "hybrid" seperates incoming and outgoing audio. In nearly all phones the hybrid circuit is crude and leaky which is why you can hear yourself in the earpeice.

The only thing that has really changed about the interface phones use is the method of dialling. Old phones pulsed the DC load they place on the phone line on and off. Modern phones send DTMF tones. For many years phone exchanges accepted both but I believe support for pulse dialing is now being phased out by some providers.

Comment: The old coin-operated payphones also used a DTMF to signal when money is inserted. It used to be possible to spoof this by playing the correct DTMF directly into the mouthpiece. When this got to be too much of a problem, they added countermeasures to prevent it from working.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_(telephony) covers some things not said here like how two- or multi-party lines worked.

Comment: Also the [ringup](https://books.google.com/books?id=ITe2DyrbtdsC&pg=PA68) is an interesting issue, not even mentioned on the wiki.